# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'jpbc-pbc': The specified module could not be found

Tags: java

How can I solve this problem:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'jpbc-pbc': The specified module could not be found.
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:164)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:237) 
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
```

Comment: See this thread [trying-to-use-dll-from-java-jna-unable-to-load-library-exception][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286647/trying-to-use-dll-from-java-jna-unable-to-load-library-exception

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Java library (.jar file) that needs some native library (.dll or .so file), but JVM cannot find this native library.  The native library is probably named `jpbc-pbc.dll` or `libjpbc-pbc.so`.  Make sure you have this file and that path to it is in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (on Unix) or in your `PATH` (on Windows) or in `java.library.path` JVM property.

Comment: @Anishkumar Are you running onWindows or Unix?  Have you found `jpbc-pbc.dll`/`libjpbc-pbc.so` file?  Have you added its location to `java.library.path` JVM property using `-Djava.library.path=path-to-native-lib`?