# Calling DLL file using java getting error as java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, dll

I have a dll file which I am trying to call using my java program.

My **java program and dll file both in the same folder** `C://JNI_project`

My dll name is `JNITest.dll`

My java program is as follows:

```
public class JNITest {
   static{


      System.loadLibrary("JNITest");
   }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
     JNITest test=new JNITest();
      //test.greet();
   }
}
```

I executed the program in `cmd` as follows:

```
C:\JNI_project>javac JNITest.java

C:\JNI_project>java JNITest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key can't be empty
        at java.lang.System.checkKey(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
        at JNITest.<clinit>(JNITest.java:5)
```

**I am getting errors on run time**. Please guide me to solve this.

Comment: `System.getProperty("")` is your problem, and the exception message is pretty much telling you that too. You need to pass in a non-empty value to that method call.

Comment: @JonK can you suggest me what should I pass? I am refering this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286647/trying-to-use-dll-from-java-jna-unable-to-load-library-exception

Comment: Well I'm not sure why you're trying to set a property to the value of another property. Do you even need the call to `getProperty` in the first place?

Comment: I have changed the program like this but still i am getting error at run time                                    
             public class JNITest {
   static{
     
       
      System.loadLibrary("JNITest");
   }
  
     public static void main(String[] args) {
  JNITest test=new JNITest();
      //test.greet();
   }
}