# native library not found in resource path

Tags: java, jna

My application loads a native library (idcomm25.dll file). If I start the application from command prompt with "java -jar myapplication.jar" command, or double clicking on myapplication.jar from explorer, all is fine. 
If I start the application via a .bat (even with 'run as administrator') that contains the same command as above, when the program tries to use the library, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread ... java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library
'idcomm25': Native library (win32-x86-64/idcomm25.dll) not found in resource
path ([myapplication.jar])
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that you have both 64-bit and 32-bit JRE's installed.

When you run directly from Command Prompt, or double-click the Jar file, you run the 64-bit JRE, and the `idcomm25.dll` from the `win32-x86-64` **(64-bit)** folder will load ok.

But, a `.bat` file changes your path to 32-bit, and you end up running the 32-bit JRE, which cannot load the 64-bit `.dll` file.

You have choices:

- Qualify path to `java` in the `.bat` file to explicitly run the `java.exe` from a 64-bit Java installation.
- Add the folder for 64-bit Java to beginning of the PATH.
  This is my personal preference, so I'm in full control of which Java installation is used *(I have more than 10 different JDK versions on my machine, for backward compatibility testing)*.
- Uninstall 32-bit Java JRE *(unconfirmed if this works)*.
- Change code that calls `loadLibrary` to load 32-bit version, e.g. from a `win32-x86-32` folder, if running in 32-bit JVM. See "[How can I tell if I'm running in 64-bit JVM or 32-bit JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2062020/5221149)".

See also: [Trying to use DLL from Java (JNA). Unable to load library exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14286647/5221149)

Comment: That's it! The dll is a 32bit one, env var PATH points to a 32 bit jvm, while JAVA_HOME a a 64 bit one: so the different behaviour.